# Left navigation stays the same

Tags: sharepoint-online, left-navigation

Please let me know if anyone has seen this weird behavior in SharePoint Online.

I have a sub-site under a main site collection, it's a team site (ex: https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test1/HR). It has bunch of links in the left navigation, one of the links is to a separate sub-site under a different site collection (ex: https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test2/performace) and it has its own left navigation which very basic, just 2 links.

By default the links open in the same tab, the weird thing is if we go to the performance site it opens in the same tab. That's well and good but if we click back in the browser it goes back to the HR site but the second site's left navigation stays, it doesn't update to the site 1's navigation.

Has this happened to anyone? Please let me know, thanks. (users don't want the site to open in separate window or tab, they want it to open in same tab)

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced this issue in my SPO test environment, on all browsers.

This is a typical **performance issue** in SharePoint Online. The same happens to all modern sites when you switch between them quickly.

The Quick Launch/Navigation takes a lot more time to render when you access a SPO site. It loads back when the page gets refreshed.

However, if you use Structure Navigation with “Enable caching” selected, the issue does not happen since the option brings improved performance.
The issue does not happen either if one of the sites is using classic homepage.